# Changing of game states in pygame crashes it

Tags: python, pygame

so i'm doing the states of my game right now :

```
import pygame
import sys
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((1200,700))
play_image=pygame.Surface((100,200))
play_image.fill('red')
play_rect=play_image.get_rect(topleft=(200,200))
retry_image=pygame.Surface((100,200))
retry_image.fill('red')
retry_rect=retry_image.get_rect(topleft=(200,200))
game_over=False
menustatus=True
while menustatus:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            pygame.font.quit()
            sys.exit()
    mouse_pos=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    mousecheck=pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if play_rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos) and mousecheck[0]:
        game_over=True
        menustatus=False
    screen.blit(play_image,play_rect)
    pygame.display.update()

while game_over:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            pygame.font.quit()
            sys.exit()
    mouse_pos=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    mousecheck=pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if retry_rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos) and mousecheck[0]:
        menustatus=True
        game_over=False
    screen.blit(retry_image,retry_rect)
    pygame.display.update()
```

problem is, when i click the red rectangle, which is a placeholder for my play button to head into the gameover screen, it crashes instead of showing me a game over screen

Comment: I think we need to see how this code fits into the event loop.

Comment: what do you mean by that, like the other code also in the loops themselves?

Comment: I was under the impression that almost all code in a pygame app should be called from within the event loop. If not, then I assume that the app will appear to crash.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mre].

Comment: alright edited it, apologies for it being so long but paste the code and when you run it and click the red rectangle it should crash

Comment: But what happened to the "game active" part? Your code looks fine with the unusual repeats of the event loop code. (It would be more normal to have one event loop calling a statemachine)

Comment: Right, i forgot to remove that. my original game had 3 states but i shrunk it down to 2 as it was enough to produce the problem. (my game closing)

Comment: So ... your game just stops because there is no more code? That's quite normal for programs. Did you mean to have an overall loop to start again? I really think you should consider a state machine.

Comment: i don't know the cause of it but i assume that is the case. What is a state machine? I feel as though the program should theoretically run, since when i change the state another state will be ran but is it because in between the changing, theres a moment where both are false? that's my only theory

Comment: Yes, I thought as much. You are thinking that the program is written declaratively, so you declare that there are states and the program should work out which to run. Unfortunately python, like many languages, is imperative and just runs one line after the previous. I shall try to write an answer which demonstrates a simple state machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written a function `state_machine()` which decides what is happening and what to do next, but is uses states to 'jump' from one thing to another:

```py
import pygame
import sys
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((1200,700))
play_image=pygame.Surface((100,200))
play_image.fill('red')
play_rect=play_image.get_rect(topleft=(200,200))
retry_image=pygame.Surface((100,200))
retry_image.fill('red')
retry_rect=retry_image.get_rect(topleft=(200,200))

def state_machine(state):
    if state == "menu_status":
        if play_rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos) and mousecheck[0]:  #checks if player clicks a button to play
            state = "game_over"
    elif state == "game_over":
        if retry_rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos) and mousecheck[0]: #checks if player clicks a button to retry
            state = "game_active"
    elif state == "game_active":
        if player.rect.y>screen_height: #checks if player dies
            state = "game_over"
    return state

game_state = "menu_status"

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            pygame.font.quit()
            sys.exit()
    mouse_pos=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    mousecheck=pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    game_state = state_machine(game_state)

    screen.blit(play_image,play_rect)
    pygame.display.update()
```

I've not run this code because I'm not sure I've captured everything from your code.